# I'm getting so many errors when updating the Appium dotnet driver, is there any way to fix them?

Tags: appium, dot-net

I just updated my Appium dotnet driver from 3.0.0.2 to 4.0 and I got so many errors and warnings on the code.

My major concerns are that it says `Driver.tap`, `Driver.swap` are not available and it's giving me an error at the driver initialisation line where I add the server IP address and the URL.

What are the possible solutions?

[image: screenshot of IDE showing issues]

Comment: 4.0 is a new *major* version - did you check to see whether there are API changes you need to adjust your code for?

Comment: Yeah I tried but no luck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look at the Appium Dotnet Driver changelog (https://github.com/appium/appium-dotnet-driver/releases) you can see the 4.x version is nearly 2 years in beta. It contains a lot of breaking changes, around 2-3 years of them. What you are getting is normal with major version upgrades. The programming interface (API) changes in major version to handle new insights and a changing world.

In the code example you show the AndroidDriver is changed to use a `AppiumServiceBuilder.getUrl()` instead of a `System.Uri`. This page has some examples: https://github.com/appium/appium-dotnet-driver/wiki/How-to-start-an-AppiumDriver-locally

I would **rollback to 3.x**, unless there is a 4.x feature I really need now. Then I would 
 reserve some time to implement an experiment with the new version and with that knowledge change the old test code to meet the new requirements.

Comment: Wow, Nice explanation Boss.Thanks.